# Let $A$ be the set of all $4$ digit numbers $a_1a_2a_3a_4$ such that $a_1 < a_2 < a_3 < a_4$, then what is $n(A)$ equal to?

Tags: combinatorics

How can you solve this problem relatively quickly using combinatorics? I found it really interesting.

Let $A$ be the set of all $4$ digit numbers $a_1a_2a_3a_4$ such that $a_1 < a_2 < a_3 < a_4$, then what is $n(A)$ equal to?

Comment: Please let us know your workings so far.

Comment: Btw,a more interesting question can be asked when $a_1\le a_2\le a_3\le a_4$.

Comment: I drew a huge diagram, mapping all the possibilities and I counted the possibilities where a4 = 4,5,6...9 and got when a4 = 4 then there is 1 number and when it is 5, there are 1+2 numbers and 1+2+3 numbers and so on

Comment: Why would that be more interesting?

Comment: Hint:If you randomly take 4 digits without repetition,there is **only** one 4 digit number using those digits that satisfy your restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

**HINTS:**

**1)** Your restrictions say that the number cannot have repeated digits.

**2)** Using $4$ randomly selected digits,all of which are distinct,in how many ways can you arrange them in descending order?

This is a "counting combinations" question,although at first sight it appears to be a "permutations" question.

Comment: So for every selection of 4 digits, there is only one number satisfying the condition

Comment: @user34034 Yes,precisely.

Comment: Is the answer 9C4

Comment: Because 0 can not be included

Comment: But this is more than 9999, what mistake am I making?

Comment: Yes,since if 0 is among our four chosen integers,it has to be the first digit(why?).But then our number won't be a four digit number.So we are allowed to  choose from the digits $1$ through $9$.That can be done in $\dbinom{9}{4}$ ways.

Comment: @user34304,What is greater than $9999$?I get 126.

Answer (score 0):

$7,6,5,4,3,2$ in second positions  give $6,5,4,3,2,1$ cases respectively of the  trees below in which for $7$ one has one case, for $6$ three, for $5$ six, for $4$ ten, for $3$ fifteen, and for $2$ twenty one cases (these are the number of endpoints  in each tree). This gives finally 
$$6\cdot1+5\cdot3+4\cdot6+3\cdot10+2\cdot15+1\cdot21=\color{red}{126\text{ cases }}$$

[image]